# Writing a print statement into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I trying to write the print statement of the following python program in a csv file.

```
import optparse
import datetime
import csv
file_name='sample.txt'
with open(file_name,'rb') as f:               
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")                                              
    #headers = reader.next()
    for row in reader:

        row[0] = row[0].zfill(6) 
        row[2] = row[2].zfill(6)
        row[3] = row[3].zfill(6)
        row[4] = row[4].zfill(6)
        row[1] = row[1][5:7] + "-" + row[1][8:10] + "-" + row[1][:4]
        p = row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]
        print p
with open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    writer.writerow(p)
```

The output is following:-

```
C:\Python27\office>python python_poc.py
('User_ID', '--Date', '0Num_1', '0Num_2', 'Com_ID')
('000101', '04-13-2015', '000012', '000021', '001011')
('000102', '04-03-2014', '000001', '000007', '001002')
('000103', '06-05-2013', '000003', '000004', '000034')
('000104', '12-31-2012', '000004', '000009', '001023')
('000105', '09-09-2011', '000009', '000005', '000104')
```

But my output csv file shows something like:--
[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

You [don't want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to write a `print` statement to a CSV file. The issue is that you keep overwriting `p` after every row, so only the last one is saved. That's not too hard to fix:

```
p = []
for row in reader:
    ...
    p.append(row[:5])
```

---

```
with open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    for row in p:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Or to clean up the header row:

```
with open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    writer.writerow([row[0], row[1].lstrip('-'), row[2].lstrip('0'), row[3].lstrip('0'), row[4]])
    for row in p[1:]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

---

Or, better yet (but without header row cleanup):

```
with open(file_name,'rb') as f, open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    ...
    for row in reader:
        ...
        writer.writerow(row[:5])
```

As you can see, cleaning up the header programatically can get messy (and I don't even know if the cleanup implementation is correct - what if you get a header cell of `__Date` or `-+-Date` instead of `--Date`?). Unless you're trying to generate this file automatically as part of a scheduled task or something, it makes a lot more sense to just open the file in Notepad/Excel/etc. and manually clean up the header row.

Comment: That worked!! 
How do I get rid of -- in '--Date' and 0 in '0Num_1' ?

Comment: @satyaki: str.replace(old, new[, max]) should help you with `--Date` and `0Num_1` replacement... as an example, `'--Date'.replace('--', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Your spreadsheet application is formatting the data.  Open the CSV in a text editor and you'll see the data as expected.

===UPDATE===
The problem I saw was ill-formatted data thus my comment above - which is correct.  Supposing you're inquiring about the missing records then your logic is close and @TigerhawkT3 has the answer to that.

Comment: That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your question has to do with how the data are being displayed, and not that only one line has printed out. If that assumption is wrong, then please clarify what exactly what is wrong with how the CSV is displaying.

It looks like the problem is the program you are using to view the .csv file. If you want to see what the raw .csv looks like, you should open it in a text editor like gedit or Notepad.

When you open a .csv file in a spreadsheet program, it will interpret and display the .csv output by your program, but it will format each cell according to it's own default settings. In addition, most spreadsheet programs allow you to choose how to interpret delimiters in the CSV file, which will alter whether or not all your data is imported/displayed properly.

Comment: I think it's reasonably clear that the issue is an incomplete file.

Comment: Well that's two of us that don't entirely agree with you as to the clarity of the post... sometimes people don't post solid data/samples/detail/etc and people interpret the information differently.

Comment: If you're aware of both issues as potentially being the problem at hand, I'm just surprised that you went for the trivial display issue that isn't related to Python rather than the major file content issue caused by the provided Python code.

Comment: The reason I didn't hone in on that is because there is data in the file... and it "looks" different.  My response was also driven from the lack of any mention of missing data and OP's "csv file shows something like" comment.  To me that is vague and speaks to a sample... which, again, "looks" wrong.  In addition, the logic was overall not bad so, again, I thought OP was hung on why data looked different.  Ya win some, ya lose some.  I'm far from perfect in both answering questions and asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

given the problem has been correctly identified by @TigerhawkT3 (whose solution I find excellent), let me suggest an alternative, which follows your original train of thought:

```
import optparse
import datetime
import csv
file_name='sample.txt'
with open(file_name,'rb') as f, open('names.csv', 'wb') as ofile:               
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)
    #headers = reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        row[0] = row[0].zfill(6) 
        row[2] = row[2].zfill(6)
        row[3] = row[3].zfill(6)
        row[4] = row[4].zfill(6)
        row[1] = row[1][5:7] + "-" + row[1][8:10] + "-" + row[1][:4]
        p = row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]
        print p
        writer.writerow(p)
```

The main difference is that the output file is written as the input file is being read. The performance may be slightly slower, given the buffering, but it may come in handy for high volumes of data.

Comment: Oh alright @TigerhawkT3 has updated his answer to include this approach. Choose his answer :)